# imwarp and transformPointsForward giving different results with the same warp

Tags: matlab, imaging

Trying to create an image panorama software

I am creating a projective2d warp using 4 matching points on two different images to create a square.I then center both squares to zero and work out the difference between them using fitgeotrans

i then warp the image using imwarp and the projective2d warp I have just calculated.

```
images{1,i+1} = imwarp(images{1,i+1},finalWarps(1,i));
```

I am then trying to find the new location of the 4 matching points I used to create the projective2d warp using transformPointsForward

```
transformPointsForward(finalWarps(1,i),stitchCoords{i*2});
```

The new coordinate location is not matching where it was on the pre warped image even though I am transforming the coordinates I used to calculate the warp forward using the same warp and I am seeing different results using imwarp and transformPoitnsForward

I hope this all makes sense!